# Search an array by slug or tags - javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a json object like the below

```
items: [
 {
   "slug":"foo",
   "tags":[
           {"value":"bar"},
           {"value":"baz"}
          ]
 },
 {
   "slug":"bar",
   "tags":[]
 }

]
```

I'm trying to write a function where i can search the collection either by the `slug` or `tags` provided . So if i search for "bar" , both objects should be found. If i search for "baz" - only the first object is returned etc

this is what i have so far,

```
items = items.filter((item) => {
  var regex = new RegExp( searchTerm, 'g' );

  if (item.slug.match(regex)){
    return true
  }

  item.tags.map((tag) => {
    if (tag.title.match(regex)){
      console.log('item found : ',item)
      return true
    }
  })

})
```

`searchTerm` is the search string provided.

The above code only seems to return items where the `slug` matches but tags dont seem to work. I'm assuming the problem is that the internal map function doesnt return true to the filter function ?

What is the right way to do the above? I would prefer to use plain js.

Thanks

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided an example where the tags have title attributes.  Also what types of searches are you doing?  I would use test instead of match for the regex, it is faster and suits this code better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are overwriting the original array by redefining `items` as a result of `items = items.filter((item)`.

You were also searching for `tag.title` instead of `tag.value`; `items.tags` array does not have an object element where a property is `"tilte"` at `javascript` at Question.

Substitute using `.some()` for `.map()`; `.map()` returns a new array, `.some()` returns a `Boolean`.

```js
items = [
 {
   "slug":"foo",
   "tags":[
           {"value":"bar"},
           {"value":"baz"}
          ]
 },
 {
   "slug":"bar",
   "tags":[]
 }

];

var searchTerm = "baz";

var res = items.filter((item) => {
  var regex = new RegExp( searchTerm, 'g' );

  if (item.slug.match(regex)){
    return true
  }

  return item.tags.some((tag) => {
    if (tag.value.match(regex)){
      console.log('item found : ',item)
      return true
    }
  })

})

console.log(res)
```

Comment: Thank you for `some` ..  that makes the entire thing work .. i manually wrote the json object so there was an error.. it should be `value`

Answer (score 0):

Or just :

```
var items = [
   {
     "slug":"foo",
     "tags":[
       {"value":"bar"},
       {"value":"baz"}
      ]
    },
    {
      "slug":"bar",
       "tags":[]
     }
];
var searchTerm = "baz";
var regex = new RegExp( searchTerm, 'g');
results = items.filter(item => (item.slug.match(regex) || item.tags.some(tag => tag.value.match(regex))));
console.log(results);
```